# OpenWRT failsafe mode is not starting on Netgear WNR1000v2

Tags: openwrt

I just installed Chaos Calmer (trunk) plus the system upgrade on my Netgear WNR1000V2. Every thing went well (LuCi, etc.) up to a point I messed up the FW setting. ouuups !

Now I am trying to accces the appliance in failsafe mode, but even if I succeed to boot in failsafe mode (with ping 192.168.1.1 answering rightly), I do not succeed, the device remains unreachable (telnet, ssh, http, etc.) all remain unsuccessful targeting 192.168.1.1 from client at 192.168.1.200/24

after a large number of hours I finally succeeded, here is what I learnt and what I did:

  the WNR1000V2 has a PCB 2976333104 on which you can find an UART at J2 position the details are >>>
  [here](http://csmatt.com/notes/?p=76)
  be careful it is a 3.3V UART (not a 5V)

WNR1000V2 failsafe mode is achieved by keeping the reset button (the small hole at the rear) pressed all the time from before power-on to when the power led flashes continuously one flash per second (20 to 30 second should enough but if you are not sure take 1 minute)

. To verify that the WNR1000V2 is well is failsafe mode try to ping 192.168.1.1 (should the VNR1000V2 address) from a client at the static address like 192.168.1.10/24.

  if it works you have a great chance to recover your WNR1000V2 with one of two procedure: 1/via ethernet or 2/via the UART

  via ethernet the procedure explained >>>
  [here](http://cyberstorm.altervista.org/wag354g/guides/howto_unbricking_wag354g_en.txt)
  worked perfectly for me

  Qwant search engine was thousand times more useful than Google to gather all the puzzle pieces - I have now decided to switch to Qwant

Big thanks to all the people who wrote the text in the two links I mentioned as well as fossil who gave me a comment.

Hoping this will help all WNR1000V2 lucky owners to keep there device lively.

Comment: I am sure you know the IP address of router will be 192.168.1.1. Just in case you missed, you need to statically set the IP address of your laptop/computer to 192.168.1.X/255.255.255.0. The X can be 2 and above.